# Ubuntu on Razer Blade Stealth 4K

Tags: laptop, screen, crash, 4k-monitor

I am running Ubuntu on the Razer Blade Stealth and it works wonderfully except for the irritating problem where it crashes and the screen goes into grainy multi-color static.

The only resolution I can get is to hard shutdown the laptop and restart it. I'm curious to use the openrazer-meta package to see if that works. Has anyone had luck with it? things to watch out for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same thing with two different problems

1) It may be caused by caps lock, you have to disable it
2) GDM caused some errors (after reinstallation it disappeared), so I switched to lightdm

check this page https://github.com/rolandguelle/razer-blade-stealth-linux